# Sql Query Issue in joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am using two tables `tblMeet(roomid,meetid,timein,timeout,roomname,user,date)` and `tblMeetRoom(roomid,roomname,pc,phone,projector,capacity,location)` where the `roomid,roomname` is foreign key in `tblMeet`.

What I need is this:
 Select all such roomids from tblMeet where date=sysdate and time in and time out do not overlap with parameters passed and having such resources as specified in parameters provided by user(pc,phone,projector), then I need the remaining unallotted rooms from tblMeetRoom(should such rooms exist). Any allotted room goes to populate tblMeet while when a room info is created, it populates tblMeetingRoom.

I created this stored procedure for this purpose:
parameters :paramdate,paramtimein,paramtimeout,paramdate,parampc,paramphone,paramprojector

```
select roomname
from tblmeet 
where
    (date=paramdate 
    and (paramtimein not between (timein and timeout))
    and paramtimeout not between(timein and timeout)))
except 
    select roomname
    from tblmeet
    where (date=paramdate
           and (paramtimein between (timein and timeout))
           and paramtimeout between(timein and timeout))
union

select roomname
from tblmeetroom
where(phone=paramphone
      and pc=parampc
      and projector=paramprojector)
except
    select roomname 
    from tblmeetroom 
    where(date=paramdate 
          and (paramtimein not between (timein and timeout))
          and paramtimeout not between(timein and timeout)))
```

However, The result I get is, that instead of crossing out allotted rooms with overlapping time slots, it is rerning rooms where paramtimein and paramtimeout are strictly between colum values of timein and time out. That is if there is a room which has been allotted for 11:30 to 12:45, it will be shown booked if paramtimein and paramtimeout are like 11:45 to 12:30 but if paramtimein and paramtimeout are like 11:45 to 12:50, This still shows this room available...

Please help with any logical error that might have crept up. Thanks.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server 2010 if you meant sql server..

Comment: There is no sql server 2010. there is sql server 2008, 2008R2 and then 2012 and more recently 2014. I believe you're referring to Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: then that would be it.. Actually I am not sure.. it could beSQL server 2012..

Comment: Ok. Could you please edit your question, to add some data in the tables. That will help you get a quicker response. You could also create a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d73e5/1) like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without taking time to fully understand the problem, I suspect your test for overlapping time ranges is flawed. You are checking for any conflict where your start and stop times *both* lie within the start and stop times you are checking. If they are *both* within that range, then you are only finding conflicts where your test range is entirely within the existing ranges. If you want *any* overlap, you need merely to require that the test range starts before the existing ranges end and that the test range ends after the existing ranges start. It's hard to explain but the code is actually shorter than your BETWEEN concepts. See this example, which doesn't address your entire problem set but focuses just on finding an available room given a desired time range.

```
DECLARE @tblmeet TABLE (roomname varchar(50), timein datetime, timeout datetime);
DECLARE @paramtimein datetime, @paramtimeout datetime;
INSERT INTO @tblmeet (roomname, timein, timeout) values ('A', '2014-04-18 9:00 AM','2014-04-18 9:14 AM');
INSERT INTO @tblmeet (roomname, timein, timeout) values ('A', '2014-04-18 9:15 AM','2014-04-18 9:45 AM');
INSERT INTO @tblmeet (roomname, timein, timeout) values ('B', '2014-04-18 9:00 AM','2014-04-18 9:29 AM');
INSERT INTO @tblmeet (roomname, timein, timeout) values ('B', '2014-04-18 9:30 AM','2014-04-18 10:29 AM');
INSERT INTO @tblmeet (roomname, timein, timeout) values ('B', '2014-04-18 10:30 AM','2014-04-18 11:29 AM');
INSERT INTO @tblmeet (roomname, timein, timeout) values ('C', '2014-04-18 10:00 AM','2014-04-18 10:29 AM');
INSERT INTO @tblmeet (roomname, timein, timeout) values ('C', '2014-04-18 11:00 AM','2014-04-18 11:29 AM');

-- test input:

SELECT
    @paramtimein = '2014-04-18 9:15 AM',
    @paramtimeout = '2014-04-18 9:45 AM';

-- conflicts:

SELECT
    *
FROM        @tblmeet
WHERE       (
                @paramtimein <= timeout
            AND
                @paramtimeout >= timein
            );

-- available rooms:

SELECT
    roomname
FROM        @tblmeet

EXCEPT

SELECT
    roomname
FROM        @tblmeet
WHERE       (
                @paramtimein <= timeout
            AND
                @paramtimeout >= timein
            );
```

Note that I haven't well considered edge cases. For example, should the system allow an 11:00 AM to 11:30 AM meeting when there is already a 10:30 AM to 11:00 AM meeting? Technically, the 11:00 AM time is an overlap, but humans generally don't consider that an overlap.

Also, I will point out that it looks like you are requiring that a room have some existing bookings into order to be considered for future bookings. It looks like you should simply have a list of room names somewhere. Perhaps I just haven't fully comprehended your design given the information provided.

Comment: Actually, what I am doing is selecting rooms allocated from tblMeet ,then subtracting those rooms that do not match user's resource filter requirement, then from the list of all available rooms in tblMeetroom I only pick the rooms which haven't been in tblMeet and apply filter criteria, then by union take result of both tables. Resource filter being conditions on(pc,phone,projector)

Comment: Ok, but you still have the same overlapping time ranges, right? The code I provided addresses that.

Comment: yes it does. In,fact my first approach was that only but due to so many conditional checks, I tried the reduction to this between and not between operators. now my problem is resolved and working exactly as needed.